# How to get CGPDFDictionaryRef keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf, dictionary

I would like to get all the keys of an CGPDFDictionaryRef. so far this what I found [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061310/cgpdfdictionary-keys)

Here is my code in swift:

```
 func printPDFKeys(key: UnsafePointer<Int8>, ob: CGPDFObjectRef, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void{

 NSLog("key = %s", key);
   //return (key, ob , info)
  }
```

This function is then called like this.

```
     let myDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)
    if myDoc != nil {
    let myCatalog=CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(myDoc)

       CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(myCatalog, printPDFKeys, nil);//Compiler error here
     }
```

However I am getting an error that

> a c function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func'
>   or a literal closure

I have also tried  using a Closure like this:

```
var printPDFKeys: (  UnsafePointer<Int8>, CGPDFObjectRef,  UnsafeMutablePointer<()> )-> Void

    printPDFKeys={
        key,ob,info in

    NSLog("key = %s", key);

    }
```

I am still getting the same error. How could I go about it

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your code but it couldn't work for me. Would you please add a complete answer here so it will be helpful to future readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct closure syntax would be:

```
CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(myCatalog, { (key, object, info) -> Void in
// do something
}, nil)
```

Comment: Can you add a full answer as per the question?