# How to get CGPDFDictionary Keys

Tags: swift, pdf, cgpdfdictionaryref

There is a question about using Swift to get the dictionary keys from a PDF file here:
[How to get CGPDFDictionaryRef keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589516/how-to-get-cgpdfdictionaryref-keys)

An answer has been given, which is just one line of code, but I don't see how it fits with the original code in the question. Can anyone elaborate it?

Comment: Check this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1430216-cgpdfdictionaryapplyfunction?changes=latest_major

Comment: In the answer, in //do something, try to print key, object and info.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes, thanks.
The line in the answer replaces the entire original code.

```
    CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(cat, { (key, object, info) -> Void in
        print("\(key), \(object), \(info)")
    }, nil)
```

However, I'm still getting a bunch of hex digits, rather than actual data. But it's a step in the right direction.