# CGPDFDictionaryGetString function nil parameter exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, file, pdf

I found away of getting the types of content in a pdf. I built my code on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061310/cgpdfdictionary-keys) where I am trying to read the content types from the dictionary. I found out that the key for type is *Type*. However I am getting an Error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is my code:

```
pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)

if (pdfDoc != nil) {
    let pdfCatalog=CGPDFDocumentGetCatalog(pdfDoc)
    var uriStringRef: UnsafeMutablePointer< CGPDFStringRef>!

    if (CGPDFDictionaryGetString(pdfCatalog, "Type", uriStringRef)) { //error
        print(uriStringRef)

    }
}
```

The only nil parameter is `uriStringRef`. However [from the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061310/cgpdfdictionary-keys), I am not supposed to set to any value before passing to `CGPDFDictionaryGetString`, and according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDictionaryGetString), this should get the string returned value based on the key `"Type"`. Am I right?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an uninitialized pointer to the `CGPDFDictionaryGetString` method, that is unsafe because you cannot know whether the method being called tries to read from a pointer before writing to it.

From the Swift blog post [Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6):

> **Pointers as In/Out Parameters**
>
> C and Objective-C don’t support multiple return values, so Cocoa APIs frequently use pointers as a way of passing additional data in and out of functions. Swift allows pointer parameters to be treated like inout parameters, so you can pass a reference to a `var` as a pointer argument by using the same `&` syntax.
>
> For safety, Swift requires the variables to be initialized before being passed with `&`. This is because it cannot know whether the method being called tries to read from a pointer before writing to it.

So initialize the `CGPDFStringRef` 'pointer' like this:

```
var uriStringRef = CGPDFStringRef.init()
```

And pass it to the method using the inout syntax:

```
CGPDFDictionaryGetString(pdfCatalog, "Type", &uriStringRef)
```